# Http post 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post

Apologize if this is a newbie question or for using inaccurate terminology. coz I am a newbie.

I built a simple python api to read and write into a database (csv file) 
my front end is Angular 5.
I managed to get the data in full from the file on the server, but I cannot post to it. Here is the issue (it seems!)

The method I am using is post and the data is an array of JSON.

This is the code of interest:
component.ts side:

```
this._svc.postAPI(this.csvData)
    .subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
    error => alert('Error!'),
  ()=> 'Data Submitted to database') 
  }
```

services.ts side:

```
postAPI(data): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.urlAPI, data);
  }
```

Error I am getting is 405 Method Not Allowed and console's Network shows:

**General**

```
Request URL: http://192.168.0.2:5050/api
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 192.168.0.2:5050
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response Headers**

```
Allow: POST
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 03:20:39 GMT
Server: Python/3.5 aiohttp/2.3.10
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 192.168.0.2:5050
Origin: http://evil.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
```

Everything works fine using postman, the URL seems to be correct but the issue seems to be with the data itself.

I tried these:

This did NOT work:

```
postAPI(data): Observable<any>{
return this.http.post(this.urlAPI, '{}');
}
```

but this DID work:

```
postAPI(data): Observable<any>{
return this.http.post(this.urlAPI, '[{}]');
}
```

and this DID work:

```
postAPI(data): Observable<any>{
return this.http.post(this.urlAPI, '
[
    {
        "info": "A",
        "dev": "T",
        "but": "C",
        "msg": "X"
    }
]
');
    }
```

I believe the data that I am trying to post is also in this exact format, a JSON array.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your data this line this.csvData

Comment: The request is using OPTIONS, not POST. I'm guessing the API is on another domain? Then there is a CORS-preflight-request made by your browser before the actual POST. Python needs to generate a success-response to that. https://enable-cors.org

Comment: @TobiasK it shows OPTIONS when I send my data but when I tried with just '[{}]' it switches to proper POST without errors and server also successfully writes the CSV file with and empty space. And yes I have to have CORS plug-in enabled on my browser for it to work. Is it something I need to do on the server side then? or is it related to the format of my data?

Comment: I have no explanation for why the format of your data matters. I'd expect the preflight request to always happen. Yes, you have to implement the OPTIONS method and return a proper CORS response on serverside. Your end-users won't have the plugin. The plugin simply allows every request which is insecure and defeats the purpose of CORS.

Comment: Thank you very much @TobiasK for your response! I will try to learn on how to make the server success-respond to preflight-request.

Answer (score -1):

405 indicates something wrong with your script.  Considering one version works, its unlikely to be the web server.  You need to have the [] brackets for this type.

Comment: I do have brackets in data. This is how it looks if I were to console.log it.
`(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: No, HTTP 405 means you used an HTTP method (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, etc) that the server refuses to honor.